# “chosen:updated” page overflow issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two chosen dropdown  list (Jquery) in my screen. once I select a record from my first dropdown, second drop down should display a specific item from the existing list. Code is working fine but the size of the screen automatically increasee and I got a huge blank space at bottom of the page.

below is the code to select a record from second dropdown list.

```
// find the voltage from value and set the voltage drodown value
        $(ddlResType).val(value[2]);
        $(ddlResType).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Comment: share html and css code to elaborate more

Comment: could u please share your codeor a fiddle would be great

Comment: function OnResChange() {
       var selected = $("#ddlResource option:selected");
    selected.each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val().split(',');
        $("#ddlVoltage").val(value[1]);
        $("#ddlVoltage").trigger("chosen:updated");

//Line of code which is causing the scroll bar issue

        $(ddlResType).val(value[2]);
        $(ddlResType).trigger("chosen:updated");


        $(ddlJurisdiction).val(value[3]);
        $(ddlJurisdiction).trigger("chosen:updated");

});

}

Comment: once I will select the record from DdlResource dropdown, the DdlVoltage and DdlResType drop shold display a perticuler value.